# CiviCRM Cannot Find Class

Tags: drupal-9, cli

I am trying to move CiviCRM and Drupal to a new server.  Everything looks to me like it should be right. I know that Drupal can connect to its database and is able to run simple drush commands. However if I try and run cv sql or cv flush I get a fatal error.

Class "ComposerAutoloaderInitDrupal8" not found

The error points to the file Drupal8.php line 414.

I am using the command line because I have multiple problems with the setup that are not allowing Apache to load the page and I am trying troubleshoot.  Of course this is probably part of the problem.

I have the following:

PHP: 8.0.30
Drupal: 9.5.11
CiviCRM: 5.64.3
CIVICRM_ROOT_PATH:  /var/aap/current/vendor

I am not sure what other relevant information I can provide.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I found the issue.  I thought the path needed to be /vendor rather than my document root.

Answer (score 0):

I'd started from cleaning up "vendors" and running "composer update".
If not work, re-install CiviCRM would.

Comment: thank you for the idea.  I have ran a composer update and it has not made a change. I am not sure what you mean by re-install CiviCRM. I cannot lose my database.  Thanks!

Comment: @Josh you won't be losing the database on re-install: just make a backup, install a fresh civcrm using another , empty database, then plug in your current db from the backup.